# How to schedule a python task created in pycharm which imports functions from other scripts in the same directory

Tags: python, module, path, pycharm, scheduled-tasks

So I wrote this script that scrapes inventory levels from rival companies on amazon. I wrote the script in pycharm and when I run it there it works fine. However, I would like to automate the searching process so that it automatically collects data a few times per day. I made a scheduled task in the windows task scheduler but it doesn't seem to do anything. I'm pretty sure the problem lies in the fact that I import functions from different files in the same directory. When I try to run the same script in the python IDLE it gives me an error that the module (which is my directory which holds the other python scripts) cannot be found (as stated before it runs fine in pycharm).

```
from Bolcom.inventoryscraper.Inventory_scraper import inventory_scraper
```

Bolcom being the main directory which holds both files.
I hope the problem is clear if so does anyone see what I can do to fix it?
thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same problem.
I use:
import sys
sys.path.append("venv\Lib\site-packages\") to solve directory problem
it seems like Pycharm put all library in different directory from the py file.

if you create you want to import your own module, you can either put your module into site-packages or use
sys.path.remove("venv\Lib\site-packages\")
sys.path.append("your module directory")

hopefully helps